# I need a free and simple bug tracking system, suggestions?

Tags: bug-tracking

We have 2 systems at work that we pay for and we don't use and I don't know why, and at the moment we're using spreadsheets and let's just say it's not the greatest solution.
So I'm going go to a little rogue and set a bugtracking system up in my dev environment and try and make people use it at least on my projects.

Any suggestions? Gotta be free, something that can run on an iplanet webserver (so cgis are best) and is really simple.
Bugzilla is too complex. Something as easy to use as wordpress would be ideal. I'm tempted to use a wiki or wordpress simply because it's less worse than a spreadsheet, but a real bug tracking system would be best.

Some of you are going to suggest "why aren't you using one of your two existing systems?" and "if you're not using your existing systems you're not going to use a new one."

That may be true, but that doesn't help me. Any suggestions for something easy to set up and easy to figure out and use? The goal is to have as close to zero learning curve as possible so as to get it adopted more quickly and easily.

Comment: There are several thorough surveys of bug tracking tools here, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/ for example. But if you're using spreadsheets and it's (sort of) working for you, why not try moving them to Google Docs for a start and see how that goes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free/Cheap Task/Bug Management software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86394/free-cheap-task-bug-management-software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) ([hosts](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommercialServices)) yet? It's generally very simple to use and has most of the features of a real bug-tracking system. You can use it for free for up to 5 users.

Comment: You can even use it with unlimited users, if you host it on your own server.

Comment: I got this set up and it does just what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I use Trac at the office with many non technical users that report errors to me. They instantly learned how to work with it. And I as a developer can use the full functionality like SVN synchronisation and Mylyn integration into Apatana (Eclipse).

The setup is quite easy, if you have a linux server that already has python activated. Just install it using easy_install as explained here: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#Usingeasy_install

I set up a multi project trac without being a python user or a linux pro. If you have any problem setting it up, just ask us.

Answer (score 3):

**JIRA** is $10 for a limited time (for 10 users)
http://www.atlassian.com/starter/

**Trac** is free and excellent
http://trac.edgewall.org/

**Unfuddle** is hosted (but free)
http://unfuddle.com/

Comment: +1 on trac, highly recommended

Answer (score 3):

try the mantis it's free and easy php solution.i cannot compare with trac or others because mantis is good enough.

http://www.mantisbt.org/

Answer (score 2):

A spreadsheet is better than a wiki or wordpress. At least a spreadsheet can have a "Status" column!

Bugzilla is highly configurable, and you can hide much of the complexity from your users.

That having been said, Trac is also a pretty nice simple solution. I have no idea if it runs on iplanet. Also, it's not so terribly easy to set up, unfortunately.

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101774/what-is-your-bug-task-tracking-tool

Answer (score 0):

I recommend JIRA above any that have been mentioned thus far. I have used Mantis,Trac,RedMine,TFS,YouTrack,Unfuddle and some other well known ones, and none of them even compare to JIRA.

JIRA is extensible and has great usability. If you are looking for a system that is easy to use and you only need small return on it, then it is perfect. While at the same time, it is able to serve some of the largest development teams.

Additionally, JIRA has a plugin system that is unmatched among other issue tracking and project management softwares. You should really look into their plugins such as Confluence,Bamboo, Crucible,Clover,etc. Which are all EXTREMELY easy to integrate into your setup, and for the low price it is...its unbeatable.

Comment: If Stu's already finding BugZilla is too complex, why would you recommend something that is even more complex like JIRA? We tried Atlassian JIRA at work and an entire team of developers and managers could not get JIRA setup anywhere close to what we wanted after a couple of weeks of trying. JIRA is not very user friendly, you need a JIRA expert to set it up.